# How can I restore my previous version of Linux after a bad video driver install?

Tags: 11.10, drivers

After I installed the ATI/AMD FGLRX graphic drivers, the display output doesn't work and my display goes to sleep. I installed the drivers through the Additional Drivers systems settings tool.

I am able to change during the boot into to my previous patch version of Linux. I'm on 11.10.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please consider these two links...

1)[Binary Driver how to ATI](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/ATI) -> this is about why fglrx is a problem and ati is recommendation

2) [How to remove fglrx completely](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Troubleshooting/FglrxInteferesWithRadeonDriver)

Just read both topics ..you will learn lot of things...

Answer (score 0):

How did you install the driver ? You can probably just remove it or delete/move your `xorg.conf`

Boot to recovery mode, start a root shell. You will be at the command line without a graphical interface

```
sudo mv /etc/X11/xorg.conf /etc/X11/xorg.conf.ati
```

exit the root shell, and continue with a normal boot

```
exit
```

Comment: Unfortunately this did not work.